# trying to print out some information of the input of the user,but didn't work

Tags: c, function

getting the input from the user and want to print out the information that he were putting.

I tried to out put of the car type but the black box did not work,Therefore, the speed gave me two result.. any idea ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int speed(int distance, int time);
void message(float speed);

int main ()
{
    char answer,name;
    int distance , time ,speed1;
    do {


    speed1=speed(distance , time);
    message(speed1);
    int speed;
    printf("\nContinue calculating speed? [Y/N] : ");
    scanf(" %c",&answer);
    }while(answer=='y' || answer =='Y');

}

int speed(int distance, int time)
{
    int speed;
    char name;
    printf("Enter car type :");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("Enter distance in kilometers : ");
    scanf(" %d",&distance);
    printf("Enter time in hour: ");
    scanf(" %d",&time);
    speed = distance / time;
    return speed;
}
void message(float speed)
{
    if (speed < 60 && speed >0)
    {
        printf("Speed: %.2f\n",speed);
        printf("Too slow!");
    }
    else if (speed <90 && speed >61)
    {
        printf("Speed: %.2f\n",speed);
        printf("Just cruising...");
    }
    else if ( speed <120 || speed >91)
    {
        printf("Speed: %.2f\n",speed);
        printf("Good speed.");
    }
    else
        printf("Speed: %.2f\n",speed);
        printf("\nDanger alert!");
}
```

Expecting the out put will be :

```
Enter car type: Alfa
Enter distance in kilometers: 300
Enter time in hours: 3 

Car type: Alfa
Speed : 300.00
Good speed
```

But it gave me

```
Enter car type: Alfa
Enter distance in kilometers: 300
Enter time in hours: 3 

Car type: Alfa
Speed : 300.00
Good speed 
Danger alert!
```

Comment: Typo: Missing braces in last `else` block.

Comment: 300 is greater than 91.  You wrote || but meant &&.

Comment: `char name` makes `name` a single character. Strings in C needs more than that to be able to store the null-terminator.

Comment: Notes 1) `char name;` is incorrect and 2) there are gaps between the speed ranges, i.e. misses 90 and 91 etc..

Comment: And why are you defining the `distance` and `time` variables in the `main` function and passing them as arguments to the `speed` function? Why not define the variables locally inside the `speed` function? Any why do your `message` function use a `float` argument, when all you pass it are `int` values? And what is the `speed` variable for in the `main` function? Etc. etc. All in all it seems you might need to take a few steps back and start over with a beginners book.

Comment: and parentheses for last else are missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here

```
else if (speed < 120 || speed >91)
```

Should be

```
else if (speed < 120 && speed >91)
```

Otherwise it's always going to be true. But what's causing your message to be printed incorrectly is the missing braces here:

```
else
        printf("Speed: %.2f\n", speed);
        printf("\nDanger alert!");
```

This way the `printf("\nDanger alert!");` will always print because it got nothing to do with the `if` block. Put `{}` around the two `printf` calls like you do with the `if` blocks above. Also, `name` needs to be an array of `char`, not just one `char`:

```
char name[20];
```

And then you can change the `scanf` call to ensure that you're not corrupting your memory if the user enters too much:

```
scanf("%19s", &name);
```

Furthermore, `int speed(int distance, int time)` doesn't need those parameters. They're uninitialized when you pass them anyway and you initialize them inside. Instead, they can be local variables in the function:

```
int speed()
{
    int distance;
    int time;
    ...
}
```

And then you can remove the `distance`, `speed` and also `name` from `main` in order to get rid of various compiler warnings about unused/uninitialized variables.